# E-mails sent through php5+htmlMimeMail are being received with random characters replaced with =

Tags: php, email, unicode, outlook, mime

currently using PHP5 with htmlMimeMail 5 (http://www.phpguru.org/static/mime.mail.html) to send HTML e-mail communications. Have been having issues with a number of recipients seeing random characters replaced with equals signs e.g.:

"Good mor=ing. Our school is sending our newsletter= and information through a company called..."

Have set e-mail text, HTML, and header encoding to UTF-8. The template files loaded by PHP for the e-mail (just include()'d text/HTML with a few php tags in them) are both encoded in UTF-8.

The interesting thing is that I can't duplicate the problem on any of my e-mail clients, and can't find any information by searching yahoo/googlies that would point me at the problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending with 8-bit encoding:

```
$message->setTextEncoding(new EightBitEncoding());
$message->setHTMLEncoding(new EightBitEncoding());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but mine was a little different. Since I stumbled upon this thread looking for the answer and it helped me find it, I thought I may as well post this related answer here.

In my case special characters were getting messed up in emails even through the actual mb_detect_encoding of the text strings being sent was "UTF-8" and if I echoed them they looked fine.

So I had to us the function

```
$message->setTextCharset('UTF-8')
```

and

```
$message->setHTMLCharset('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is related to older versions of Exchange. [Equal signs at end of line](http://www.expita.com/nomime.html#equalsign):

It may not be the quoted printable thing with high/low order characters or the encoding. Also, elsewhere on that page it says:

> **NOTE:** A bug ("feature"?) in Exchange
>   may cause line feeds to be replaced
>   with equal signs when rich text mail
>   is disabled.

Comment: Nice find! But the characters replaced aren't at the end of the line or line feeds so I'm not sure where that leaves me!